# How to block characters in EditText in Android?

Tags: android

How to block characters in `EditText` in Android?

Comment: You have 9 open questions with good answers in them, that you have not taken any action on. You might want to address that, and accept some correct answers, before you get on to asking new ones. it'll increase the inclination of others' to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an [`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to restrict input on `EditText`s. Either implement your own or use a [`NumberKeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/NumberKeyListener.html) for numeric input.